# Why 9patch does not stretch horizontally?

Tags: android, nine-patch

My problem is very easy but I couldnt solve it maybe you can give me an idea, so I tried to put an image as a linearlayout's background but it does not stretch horizontally. Right corner should be rounded as left corner, where do I make mistake?

this was the image I used

[image]

and this was the result.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/red">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/abccc"
                        android:gravity="left|center">
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/uye_girisi"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe it's wider then target area. Delete a bit from the middle, leaving only couple of pixels to stretch.

Comment: I did it. Actually if I set layout_width as wrap_content it looks very tiny.

Comment: `wrap_content`? You should assign this to background, not content.

Comment: Can you post your xml layout too please?

Comment: And, by the way, are you aware of fact, that you should name your PNG `arUmi.9.png` not `arUmi.png` for 9-patch to work?

Comment: I said If I set... the name like as you say

Comment: Are you making 9 patch with 4 pixels of corners to cover the middle area only or taking each pixel in to account while making it ?

Comment: taking each pixel into..

Comment: ok than try making 9 patch by taking only 4 pixel of each corner to get middle part into account.Remember ,the part of the image overridden by the intersection of the straight lines passing from these 4 pixels will not get stretched .This is just an option in the case you want to try .

Comment: Try applying it to `TextView` instead of `LinearLayout`. And why is your `LinearLayout` has 0dip? Is it related to your 9patch LL or did you just cut some part of it? You can send me code if you want me take a look

Comment: it has 0dip because as you see I'm trying to set linearlayout's width using layout_weight so the problem is not related to it. That was the whole code, actually top of them there is another layout but it's inessential.